# selectableItemBackground with onTouchEvent and GestureDetector

Tags: android, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

Top layout is `FrameLayout` with foreground set to `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground.` Upon click, ripple is triggered. Now, I need to add double tap as well as single tap listener. After implementing a `GestureDetector` (along with `onTouchListener`), I can respond to those 2 events, but the ripple is gone. I tried to `performClick`, `callOnClick`, `drawableHotspotChanged` or `dispatchDrawableHotspotChanged`, still no ripple.

Any idea?